# How to convert a object expression to lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I am new to Android development. Recently I am learning Kotlin and I am trying to figure out setOnClickListener. However, I encountered a problem in the process of converting object expression to lambda using Kotlin.

step 1. setOnClickListener in Java:

```
buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // my code
            }
        });
```

step 2. then I convert Java code to Kotlin code using object expression:

```
buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                // my code
            }
        })
```

step 3. then IntelliJ prompts me to convert object expression to lambda:

```
buttonLogin.setOnClickListener {
        // my code
    }
```

It looks more concise, however, I can't understand the logic behind step 3.
So I checked some information online, it says

> Any function that receives an interface with a single function can be
> substituted by a lambda

It does on setOnClickListener.
But I still can't fully understand, so I defined an interface and class to verify it.

Here is my code:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun method1()
}

class MyClass {
    fun method2(myInterface: MyInterface) {
        myInterface.method1()
    }
}

fun main() {
    val myClass = MyClass()
    myClass.method2(object : MyInterface {
        override fun method1() {
            println("Hello, world.")
        }
    })
    
    // So how to write the lambda to replace object expression?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in step 3 is called trailing lambdas

According to Kotlin convention, if the last parameter of a function is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding argument can be placed outside the parentheses,

If the lambda is the only argument in that call, the parentheses can be omitted entirely:

For example:

```kotlin
fun function(f : (String) -> Unit) {

}

fun main() {
    function {
        
    }
}
```

Check the Kotlin Documentation for this feature

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas

You can convert your code to use this feature

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    fun method2(function: () -> Unit) {
        function()
    }
}

fun main() {
    val myClass = MyClass()
    myClass.method2 {
        println("Hello, world.")
    }

    // Or you can store the lambda in variable and use it like tihs
    val myClass2 = MyClass()
    val function = {
        println("Hello, world.")
    }
    myClass2.method2(function)

}
```

Or just add convert your interface to a functional interface

```kotlin
fun interface MyInterface {
    fun method1()
}

class MyClass {
    fun method2(myInterface: MyInterface) {
        myInterface.method1()
    }
}

fun main() {
    val myClass = MyClass()
    myClass.method2 { 
        println("Hello, world.") 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sir. Could you please help me complete my code using lambda (that is MyClass.method2) ?

Comment: Sure, i have updated my answer with the new code

Comment: Sir, thank you for your quick reply. So, if I want to convert object expression to lambda, I need to redefine MyClass.method2 like what you wrote above. Is that correct? Going back to setOnClickListener, why can IntelliJ convert object expression to lambda without redefine setOnClickListener method?

Comment: Yes bro, and i have added another answer, for your last question how Kotlin convert it, it really didn't redefine it, but OnClickListener is a functional interface which is an interface with only one function so this syntax sugar in Kotlin and in the answer i added example on it in Kotlin

Comment: You just saved my life! This problem has bothered me for several days. I didn't realize that functional interface in Kotlin need to be prefixed with fun. That's why I couldn't pass the compiler. Thanks again for your patient help.

Comment: You're most welcome bro, btw this feature can be used also with the same syntax with java functional interface even if you didn't annotated it with FunctionalInterface